# Why does bootstraps d-flex class stop my div from stretching 100% width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I've got a div wherein I want two elements to set side by side: a search input field and corresponding search submit button.

So far I've tried to accomplish this with the following code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

<div class="container w-100 mt-4 border-bottom pb-3 h-25 align-content-center" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-1 position-relative d-flex align-items-center"><span class="mh-100" style="line-height: 1rem">Class20</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-7 mw-100 align-items-center position-relative d-flex">
    <form action="" class="justify-content-center position-relative m-0">
     <input type="search" name="" value="" placeholder="search" class="w-100 align-items-center pl-3" id="search">
    </form>
    <button class="btn-outline-primary"type="submit">Search</button>
   </div> <!--column 7-->
   <div class="col-4">
    <button class="btn-outline-primary"type="submit">Log In</button>
    <button class="btn-outline-primary"type="submit">Sell your stuff</button>
   </div> <!-- col-4 -->
  </div> <!--row-->
</div>
```

The d-flex does what I want. It puts the search field and the button side by side. The problem I'm encountering is that it also leaves about 4 columns of white space between that div and the next. In other words, it doesn't stretch the full 7 columns I've specified. How can I resolve that issue, without pushing my button to the next line?

Comment: in your snippet you haven't included bootstrap so we don't know what result you are getting. Please edit the snippet so it looks just like the result you are getting in your project

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added the bootstrap css CDN. Check it out at in full screen to see what I'm talking about, as it's not optimized for smaller screen widths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, your `col-7` ( which contains the input and button )  has the right width, the problem is that your input and button do not cover the whole width of their parent  ( the col-7 ) .

So you can add some bootstrap classes to the input ( for eg `col-8` ) and to the button ( for eg `col-4` ). That way they will cover the whole width of their parent.

You can also style them directly with CSS ( give them custom widths in % ) or use other bootstrap classes ( col-9 col-3 etc. )

**OR** you could add

```
.d-flex form{
  flex-grow: 1
}
```

this way , the input will occupy all the remaining space inside the `col-7` parent

See example in snippet below ( using col-8 and col-4 ) or [**jsFIddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f4pjxvbL/2/)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container w-100 mt-4 border-bottom pb-3 h-25 align-content-center" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 position-relative d-flex align-items-center"><span class="mh-100" style="line-height: 1rem">Class20</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-7 mw-100 align-items-center position-relative d-flex">
      <form action="" class="justify-content-center position-relative m-0 col-8">
        <input type="search" name="" value="" placeholder="search" class="w-100 align-items-center pl-3 " id="search">
      </form>
      <button class="btn-outline-primary col-4" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
    <!--column 7-->
    <div class="col-4">
      <button class="btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Log In</button>
      <button class="btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Sell your stuff</button>
    </div>
    <!-- col-4 -->
  </div>
  <!--row-->
</div>
```

Bootstrap splits the elements widths into 12 columns. 100% = 12 col-1. So if you want two side-by-side elements to cover the full width of the parent, their 'column numbers' must add up to 12. ( col-8 and col-4 , col-6 col-6, col-9 col-3 etc. )

Comment: That's perfect. I had tried to research it but had gotten a little tunnel vision on that d-flex class. Turns out it was more an error in the way I set my col structure up. I appreciate it! I'll patch this up.

Comment: @A.Eakins Glad i could help. Also ( as i edited my answer ) you could use `.dflex form { flex-grow:1}` . Without adding new classes. This way the form ( input ) will grow and cover all the remaining space inside the `dflex` parent . ( it will have width = dflex width - width of button )